# Set popover in gauge needles (Echarts)

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have this code, where I tried to hover over the first gauge needle to get a .popover({...}) object:

```html
 <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <title>Gauge Chart</title>
    </head>
    
    <button id='btn1'>
      Let's
    </button>
    
    <input id='slider1' type='range' value='34' min='0' max='100' step='.01'>
    <input id='slider2' type='range' value='89' min='0' max='100' step='.01'>
    
          <div id='chartid1' style='width:390px; height: 410px;'></div>
          
    <script>
      const chart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chartid1'));
    
      function update1(value1, value2) {
        option = {
          series: [{
            type: 'gauge',
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            splitNumber: 10,
            detail: {
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontSize: 14,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#020202',
              borderRadius: 5,
              width: 32,
              height: 20
            },
            data: [{
              value: value1,
              name: 'False',
              itemStyle: {
                color: '#dd4b50'
              },
              title: {
                offsetCenter: ['-20%', '20%']
              },
              detail: {
                offsetCenter: ['-20%', '36%'],
                backgroundColor: '#dd4b50',
                color: '#f2f2f2'
              }
            },
            {
              value: value2,
              name: 'True',
              itemStyle: {
                color: '#3a9e4b'
              },
              title: {
                offsetCenter: ['20%', '20%']
              },
              detail: {
                offsetCenter: ['20%', '36%'],
                color: '#f2f2f2',
                backgroundColor: '#3a9e4b'
              }
            }
            ]
          }]
        };
    
        chart1.setOption(option);
      }
    
      function update2() {
        let value1 = Number($('#slider1').val());
        let value2 = Number($("#slider2").val());
        update1(value1, value2);
      }
    
      update2();

  
      document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', 
       function() {
       update2();
      })
    
      /// clickable
      chart1.on('mouseenter', {dataIndex:0}, function(params) {
        $(this).popover({
          html: true,
          sanitize: false,
          title: 'Title ',
          content: 'This a text',
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'top',
          container: 'body'
        })
      })
    
    
    </script>
```

I need to hover and get a .popover. I know I could use `tooltip:{...}`, but for a specific case, I need to configure a .popover. I tried to adjust the code above with `mychart1.on(...` but it didn't work. I added the CDN of all the code requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events.mouseover) the event is called `mouseover`, not `mouseenter`. [Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWxgCeIWxA5AOYCGAri1kwDRUUAthGjEADP2rpBbAB7EAjGIkD0GEABsIYAHIdBAI1yKVU2ABMsYNhA3FUZ9ADMYYAGJthG2swAybMGA-VQoXaDAAZQgAL0ZYBQAWSUcDYBxLHAB1CHMwAAtFZLNU9NwAYWANNOYAYjEAJgaG4MdYEoyAJTZzCA4iWABWIqkAdxz84gBmeuHqPKwIFjywYkaQgF9ZiwC2YjJWh1bYADc2DQ44yaSQ6mhPOKYPDWwWo-0sQQi6DTjDo9gAMaVaqwJg1czmBIGAZiJg3CibeHoSBgH72JEUYBOJzYMBlLDhYykJgAWkaAFI-KCKUwALoYxH_SzWWzo_7oLE4qz4wk4Pakmm8UGTABslNpW2KbABAGsWDhgBxoOYKlU-aDwZDobDJVIgWrak56kajXD_ut4YzHH9HKdznEABwATl16DuggeABUcBdXq13p9vr8Meh9SCwZM2E6sFCzUcra0UWjKOzYJzcTywESSExBdSxOKGa6LFYbHYU-z09yCVn1Tm80xReLi6HgeqwSbjfU_UcDNK5QqlSq27VI9HYwzLSF6dQLeh6esANwoFeCWhlPJsHBgAB0MAAFExBIrsMBjrgqUhzDsAJLKrDyWBiTawJxKgGQA8gLeeDAASgrIFoAwSosB3KoWH3b8cF_P9l3WOCgA) is your example:

```js
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'gauge',
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      splitNumber: 10,
      detail: {
        fontFamily: 'Lato',
        fontSize: 14,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#020202',
        borderRadius: 5,
        width: 32,
        height: 20
      },
      data: [
        {
          value: 34,
          name: 'False',
          itemStyle: {
            color: '#dd4b50'
          },
          title: {
            offsetCenter: ['-20%', '20%']
          },
          detail: {
            offsetCenter: ['-20%', '36%'],
            backgroundColor: '#dd4b50',
            color: '#f2f2f2'
          }
        },
        {
          value: 89,
          name: 'True',
          itemStyle: {
            color: '#3a9e4b'
          },
          title: {
            offsetCenter: ['20%', '20%']
          },
          detail: {
            offsetCenter: ['20%', '36%'],
            color: '#f2f2f2',
            backgroundColor: '#3a9e4b'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


myChart.on('mouseover', {dataIndex: 0}, function(params) {
  console.log(params);
});
```

Comment: Even if I change the event name to `mouseover`, `popover` doesn't work.

Comment: This was the most obvious thing i spotted. I dont know anything about popovers.. Are you getting some error now?